# Tcl: string matching the backslash

Tags: string, tcl, match

How can I match a backslash `\` in Tcl? I did the follwoing:

```
% set a "\\"
\
% string length $a
1
% string match $a "\\"
0
% string match "\\" "\\"
0
% string match $a \\
0
% string match $a [set x "\\"]
0
```

But as seen above none of them help. I want to match `$a`.

Comment: I was not just curious here, I needed it for real problem, parsing a Tcl file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to match is

```
string match {[\]} \\
# => 1
string match {a[\]} a\\
# => 1
```

Documentation: [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: Thank you. It would be helpful if you could locate the exact position in the link  you cited, which address this specific question.

Comment: @DurgaDatta: this exact problem/solution isn't addressed in the documentation. The glob syntax used in `string match` is limited, quirky, and a bit underdefined, and unfortunately locked in wart-compatibility with the early Unix editions from whence it came.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the "Pattern Ending in Backslash" section in the [`string match` documentation](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4385), it says:

```
A pattern ending in a backslash doesn't match a string ending in a backslash. Bug?
string match a\\ a\\
# -> 0
```

Using `string equal` works though:

```
% string equal $a "\\"
1
```

Comment: I saw that, but does not help.

Comment: It helps in the sense that you know it's a bug. If there were a workaround, it would already be noted there, right?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Nobody has ensured that its a bug. However, that fact that it is noted in Tcler wiki is helpful.

Comment: My particular problem is better solved by `match equal`. Thanks. The other answer of @Hoodiecrow , corrects the mistake in the approach I took.

Comment: It isn't actually a bug, it's just that the pattern goes through two rounds of substitution, once when the invocation is evaluated by Tcl, and once when the command gets ready to do the match (the string argument is only subjected to one round of substitution). `string match a\\\\ a\\ ` works as well. Personally I prefer `string match {a[\]} a\\ `, however.